# How to share a method between two components in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, ag-grid

I have an Ag-Grid that has certain action buttons and dynamic data getting filled from a MongoDB database. I have a method on my MasterData.Vue file that refreshes the Grid. Each action button inside my grid's record perform update/delete operations. When I click on those buttons I have designed a customized pop up modal component in another Modal.Vue file. I want to call that RefreshGrid() method in Modal.Vue. I tried using props to share the data but same thing doesn't work on method.

**MasterData.Vue Script**

```
<script>
import { AgGridVue } from 'ag-grid-vue';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import gridEditButtons from '@/components/GridEditButton';
import MasterModal from '@/components/MasterModal';
export default {
  name: 'masterData',
  data () {
    return {
      addBtnClick: false,
      delBtnClick: false,
      editVisible: false,
      selected: 'Business Area',
      dropdown_tables: [
        'Business Area',
        'Council',
        'Sub Area',
        'Type',
        'Work Flow Stage'
      ],
      gridOptions: {
        domLayout: 'autoHeight',
        enableColumnResize: true,
        rowDragManaged: true,
        animateRows: true,
        context: {
          vm: null
        }
      }
    };
  },
  components: {
    'ty-master-modal': MasterModal,
    'ag-grid-vue': AgGridVue,
    gridEditButtons
  },
  methods: {
  // Filter Grid Contents based on Dropdown selection
    RefreshGrid: function () {
      let cName;
      if (this.selected === 'Business Area') {
        cName = 'businessarea';
      } else if (this.selected === 'Council') {
      cName = 'council';
      } else if (this.selected === 'Type') {
        cName = 'typemaster';
      } else if (this.selected === 'Work Flow Stage') {
        cName = 'workflowstage';
      }
      let obj = {
        vm: this,
        collectionName: cName,
        action: 'masterData/setMasterData',
        mutation: 'setMasterData'
      };
      this.$store.dispatch(obj.action, obj);
    }
};
</script>
```

**Modal.Vue Script**

```
<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'MasterModal',
  props: {
    readOnly: Boolean,
    entryData: Object,
    addBtnClick: Boolean,
    delBtnClick: Boolean,
    editVisible: Boolean,
    selectedTable: String
  },
  data () {
    return {
      fieldAlert: false,
      isReadOnly: false,
      dialog: false,
      dialogDelete: false,
      valid: false,
      visible: false,
      disable: false
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('masterData', {
      entryState: 'entryState',
      // entryData: 'entryData',
      columns: 'columns',
      selectedRowId: 'selectedRowId'
    })
  },
  watch: {
    addBtnClick: function (newValue, oldValue) {
      this.setDialog(!this.dialog);
    },
    editVisible: function (newValue, oldValue) {
      this.setVisible(!this.visible);
    },
    delBtnClick: function (newValue, oldValue) {
      this.setDialogDelete(!this.dialogDelete);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setDialog (bValue) {
      this.dialog = bValue;
    },
    setDialogDelete (bValue) {
      this.dialogDelete = bValue;
    },
 }
};
</script>
```

Comment: you're already using vuex, so having the dispatch in one and computed in the other component, that should be enough (aside from passing a key or id when there are multiple instances). Can you clarify what you mean by: _call that RefreshGrid() method in Modal.Vue_ That method does not exist in that component

Comment: I want to invoke RefreshGrid() method from Modal.Vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a couple of ways to achieve this.

One is to use the emit

in the *MasterModal.vue* component run `this.$emit('refreshGrid')` in the parent *MasterData.Vue* component use `<ty-master-modal @refreshGrid="RefreshGrid" ...>`

if you have a *direct parent-child* relationship, this is likely the best option

Another way is just to pass a function as a prop to the child component.

`<ty-master-modal :onRefreshGrid="RefreshGrid" ...>`

and add a prop `onRefreshGrid` to *MasterModal.vue*, then you can invoke the function.

Another way, using vuex, is to add a watch to *MasterData.Vue* and watch a variable in the vuex store ie. `actionInvoker`. when `actionInvoker` changes, the action executes. To change the value, set it to 0 and increment or toggle between, or set to random value. The advantage is that you can call this from anywhere.

The problem with this (and the previous) solution is that you have functionality tied to a view/component that shouldn't be there. I would recommend a third solution, which is to push the functionality into a vuex action, and then you can call it from anywhere. This would require though that you store the `selected` variable in vuex too, and if you want to have multiple instances of Modal and Master components, a singular store will prohibit that (unless you add support for multiple instances).

Comment: So, I am taking onRefreshGrid an 'Object' type of prop. Do I need to add watch for invoking onRefreshGrid()? and call this.onRefreshGrid() in any method?

Comment: why not use **emit/on** `event`?

Comment: @NikulVyas, you can define the prop property=function, like `props: {
    'onRefreshGrid ': {
      type: Function,
      default: ()=>{}
    } }`

Comment: @NikulVyas it you're passing the function as prop (or using emit), you don't need a watch. The watch is only useful if you want the function to trigger when a variable changes value (ie. with vuex)